# debian packaging: forward-port a package from xenial to bionic

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, debuild, changelog

I am running xenial on my dev machine, but would like to provide a version of a package I maintain in a PPA for newer releases such as bionic.  When I try and just update the debian/changelog file to specify 'bionic', I (predictably) get this error:

`E: light changes: bad-distribution-in-changes-file bionic`

Is it possible to "forward-port" a package or do I need to upgrade my dev machine before I can provide a version of my package on a newer release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by using the "copy package" feature in launchpad.net.  When you copy a package you're able to specify the distro version as target.  I was never able to "cross build" a package from one distro version to another locally.